# Lie derivative from covariant derivative

Tags: lie-derivative

The directional derivative is

$\nabla_{\mathbf{v}}{f}(\mathbf{x}) = \nabla f(\mathbf{x}) \cdot \mathbf{v}$

The directional derivative on a manifold is the covariant derivative

$\begin{align}
  \nabla_\mathbf{v} \mathbf{u} 
    &= \nabla_{v^j \mathbf{e}_j} u^i \mathbf{e}_i \\ 
    &= v^j \nabla_{\mathbf{e}_j}  u^i \mathbf{e}_i \\
    &= v^j u^i \nabla_{\mathbf{e}_j} \mathbf{e}_i + v^j \mathbf{e}_i \nabla_{\mathbf{e}_j} u^i \\
    &= v^j u^i {\Gamma^k}_{i j}\mathbf{e}_k + v^j{\partial u^i \over \partial x^j} \mathbf{e}_i \\
    &= \left(v^j u^i {\Gamma^k}_{i j} + v^j{\partial u^k\over\partial x^j}\right)\mathbf{e}_k
\end{align}$

It adds a corrective term that describes how the manifold and its coordinate system changes or warps as you move from one place to another. See Christoffel symbols

The Lie derivative of a vector field with respect to a vector field on a manifold is

$\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}_X Y (p) &= [X,Y](p) \\
&= \partial_X Y(p) - \partial_Y X(p) \\
&= \nabla \mathbf{Y} \cdot \mathbf{X} - \nabla \mathbf{X} \cdot \mathbf{Y} \\
&= vector
\end{align}$

I notice that there are no corrective terms. My guess is that there are two corrective terms and that they cancel themselves out.

It would help me out if I could see the full equation with all corrective terms. I would like to add it to https://tok.fandom.com/wiki/Semi-advanced_mathematics#Covariant_derivative to show how the Lie derivative relates to the directional and covariant derivatives.

Yes I read through the other thread but it didnt answer my question

Comment: We have the Levi-Civita is torsion-free $\Gamma^k_{ij}=\Gamma^k_{ji}$, so the $X^jY^i\Gamma^k_{ij}e_k$ from $\nabla_XY$ cancels with $X^iY^j\Gamma^k_{ij}e_k$ from $\nabla_YX$.

Comment: I see. Its all starting to make sense now. I appreciate you taking the time to answer.